# ASP.NET MVC Routing: How to make my MVC URL's have .aspx extension?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I want an MVC app to have .aspx page URLs even though there will not be any physical aspx pages and I will be using the Razor view engine.

1) Is it possible to define such a route?

2) What would that route look like if I wanted a url such as, say, the one given below:

```
http://example.com/controller/action.aspx
```

and optionally

```
http://example.com/controller/action.aspx/id
```

and optionally

`http://example.com/controller/action.aspx?queryParam1=value&queryParam2=value` (and so on...)

**UPDATE**

I realize I want URL's like this:

```
http://example.com/controller/id.aspx
```

In other words, I want no specific action to be specified. A default action will process all requests.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

What I have specified in my route config is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{id}.aspx",
defaults: new { controller = "Foo", action = "Index", id = "default" }
);
```

However, while the above route does work for Url's where Id is specified such as the ones below:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar.aspx
```

It does not work when no Id is specified, such as in the case below:

```
http://example.com/foo/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it should affect all routes, you could alter the default route to look something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}.aspx/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

If you only want it for particular routes, than you could add an additional route like the one above, but with another name than `Default`, and leave the default-route as it is. You could then use the new route-pattern through its name when needed.

**Update:**

I haven't tried this, so I'm not certain, but this is what I would try:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{id}.aspx",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

*You would have to modify the default-value of the action-parameter, so that it matches whatever the of your action is.*

**Another update:**

To handle that, I believe you will have to have two routes. The first route should require an ID and specify no default id. If that route isn't matched, like in your second example, we will fall down to the second route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultWithId",
    "{controller}/{id}.aspx",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

*It is important that the most specific route comes first, and that you then fall back to less and less specific routes, since your routes will be read top-down, and as soon as a match is found, that route will be used.*

Comment: Thank you. Another 9 minutes before I mark you answer as the correct one. :-)

Comment: I've changed the question a bit. I realize I want another variety. Please review.

Comment: That's what I'd done. It doesn't work where I specify a default action. Please see my update to my update. :-)

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I am so ashamed that I'm not thinking. I usually do. Just opting out an easy route (pun intended) for this time. Thanks much.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 No worries, the easy solutions are usually (ironically) the easiest to overlook as well.